# java-lambda-Unresolved reference: variable; kotlin-'variable' is not captured

Tags: java, android, kotlin

when I use debug mode

In java code, if breakpoint in first "call" function code "int j = 0", I can evaluate variable'c' = 11.

but in "call" lambda function code "int j = 0", I cant evaluate variable'c'.

If I use the similar code in Kotlin， neither object or lambda argument evaluate the variable 'c'.

I want to use kotlin code replace java code in my project,but this phenomenon make me anxious. consider this scene: a code is running ,but sometimes one state is unexpected, I want to know some variable's value to infer the cause,like'c'(I expected c = 11,but in fact,maby c = 5, c is not used in "invoke" function, something was happened with c), but it looks like impossible

If in java code, like clickListener, I can click to trigger "invoke()" as onClick() function, then I can evaluate the "c" and other variable, then I can infer something. But in kotlin, I cant evaluate "c" if i never used "c" in function. I only know what happened in "invoke()", no way to know outside situtation in this moment.

what should I do ?(maby, android studio can not support kotlin very well like java?)

java code

```
public class TTTE {

    int c = 11;

    @Test
    public void ttt(){
        call(new Inc(){
             public void invoke(int t) {
                int j = 0;
            }
        });
        call(t->{

            int j = 0;
        });
    }
    
    private void call(Inc arg) {
        arg.invoke(1);
    }

    public interface Inc{
        public void invoke(int t);
    }
}
```

kotlin code

```
class EnvTT  {

    var c = 0

    @Test
    fun ttt(){
        var dd = 0
        val jj = 13
        call(object: Inc{
            override fun invoke() {
                var j = 0
            }
        })
    }

    private fun call(arg: Inc) {
        arg.invoke()
    }

    interface Inc{
        fun invoke()
    }
}
```

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.30"

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
```

Comment: Are you talking about inspecting variables in the debugger when your application is paused for debugging? I don't understand what you mean by "I can evaluate the "c" and other variable".

Comment: yeah, “c” is not in this method stack, thanks for YWNKM
choose corresponding method stack in frames window,then it can show the variable "c"